# join dont override result mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way of avoiding overrides if a row in a joined table is not there? If the last joined table row is NULL, it could override other table fields with same column name.

```
SELECT * FROM books
LEFT JOIN item ON books.item_id = item.item_id
LEFT JOIN stuff ON item.item_id = stuff.item_id //Not there, haha i will override item_id!
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`... mysql doesn't support that so you have to `UNION` a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM books
LEFT OUTER JOIN item ON books.item_id = item.item_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stuff ON item.item_id = stuff.item_id //Not there, haha i will override item_id!

UNION

SELECT * FROM books
RIGHT OUTER JOIN item ON books.item_id = item.item_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN stuff ON item.item_id = stuff.item_id //Not there, haha i will override item_id!
...
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: There is no FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL

Comment: nice catch... i updated with the correct select for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: So double the request every time?

Comment: well how many times do you want to do it? --- the union of a left and right will give a full join which has no filtering...

Comment: also if this answers your question please +1 :)